# Is iPhone X (model A1901) totally useless in China?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, cellular-carriers, lte

This is a screenshot from the device that I have:

[image]

I was doing research which Chinese operator is compatible with my device.

- iPhone X - Technical Specifications - https://support.apple.com/kb/SP770
- iPhone models supported by China Mobile, China Unicom, and China Telecom's LTE, 3G, and 2G networks - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202909
- What are all the differences between the iPhone X? How many different versions are there? https://everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/iphone-faq/differences-between-iphone-x-a1865-a1901-a1902-models.html

[image]

From the links above I am reaching the conclusion that my device is totally useless.

---

## More research, search engine "A1901 China"

https://www.frequencycheck.com/compatibility/dv0nTpj/apple-iphone-x-a1901-td-lte-64gb-apple-iphone-10-6/china
[image]

https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/travel-technology/1900185-iphone-x-a1901-china.html

> With Model A1901, LTE should work, but CDMA will not.

## Honestly, no idea, I'm confused now. Maybe you'll know?